# Exercise 4 of Chapter 17 in Lax's Functional Analysis (Resolvent set, Spectrum)

Tags: functional-analysis

In the following statements, $\mathcal{L}$ is a Banach algebra. $\sigma(M)$ is the spectrum of the operator, $M$. $\rho(M)$  is the resolvent set of $M$.

Here we have a definition and a theorem for functions of operators.

[image]
[image]

How to solve the following exercise?

[image]

My attempt is to use part (iv) of theorem 5. I define $f(z)=\ln(z), z\in \mathbb{C}$, and $g(z)=e^z$. But I don't know whether $f(z)$ is analytic on an open set containing $\sigma(M)$. How to use the condition that 0 can be connected to $\infty$ by curve that lies in $\rho(M)$? Or am I in the wrong direction?

Comment: Suppose the curve is simple, and that the complement $\Omega$ of the curve is a simply-connected region. Define a function $g(z)=\int_{z_0}^{z}\frac{1}{w}dw$, where the integral is along any path from a fixed $z_0\in \Omega$ to the given $z\in\Omega$, while remaining in the region which is the complement of the given curve. Then $e^{g(z)}=Cz$ where $C$ is a constant. Then the theorem applies.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Which part of the theorem applies?

Comment: Part (iv) applies.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts So, $g(z)$ is analytic on $\sigma(M)$? How can we see this from the conditions?

Comment: The integral $g$ (mentioned above) gives a holomorphic function on the plane minus the curve; this is because the region is simply connected.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Why $g(z)$ is analytic on the plane minus the curve?

Comment: The function $g$ I gave you is holomorphic in $z$ by a direct computation because any closed path integral of $1/w$ in the stated region is $0$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Since $1/w$ is holomorphic on the whole plane except $0$, it seems $g(z)$ is analytic everywhere except $0$?

Comment: Finding a global anti-derivative for a holomorphic function on a simply connected region can be done if every closed path integral of that function in the specified region is $0$. The anti-derivative is the integral in that case. What can go wrong, such as with $1/w$ is that $\int_{z_0}^{z}1/w dw$ could depend on the path, and the anti-derivative is then ambiguous, which can be resolved by selecting a region with there is no closed path in the region that encloses $0$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts I see. I think $e^{g(z)}$ should be $C|z|$? Consider $g(z)=\int_{z_0}^z\frac{1}{w}dw=log|z|-log|z_0|$ and the case that $z\in R^-$. Then, how to get rid of the absolute value to process the matrix case?

Comment: $e^{g(z)}$ is holomorphic. $C|z|$ is not.